# No value at JSON path "$"

Tags: spring, junit, jsonpath

I am testing rest controller. Here is test code:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/index/get-all"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$",hasSize(2)));
```

I get response body:

```
Body = [{"id":"123"},{"id":"1234"}]
```

And I get error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$", exception: net/minidev/json/writer/JsonReaderI
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your body returns an array with objects. To access each object in Spring MVC Test use following assertion:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("[0].id").value("123"))
.andExpect(jsonPath("[1].id").value("1234"))
```

Comment: Seems they want to evaluate the size of the array, not to access each element.

Answer (score 1):

Get the same error. 
Try to use higher version json-smart in your dependency, and exclude the lower version from the package which contains json-smart. For me, I changed my dependency to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
                <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your url: "/index/get-all" and make sure you are using the full path of your controller class.  I ran into this same issue because my url was missing a part of the path ("/Folder/").  What I had been using was "/folderId=1234" and realized I forgot to add the controller's @RequestMapping annotated part at the top of the class, so it was supposed to be "/Folder/folderId=1234".

Example controller code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/Folder")
public class FolderController {

@RequestMapping (value = "/folderId={Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Folder getFolderById (@PathVariable String folderId, HttpSession session)
    {
       // controller code
    }
}
```

The incorrect url I was using.

```
mockMvc.perform(
                            get("/folderId=1234")
                                     .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                     .andDo(print())
                                     .andExpect(jsonPath("$",hasSize(2)));
```

Correct url.

```
mockMvc.perform(
                        get("/Folder/folderId=1234")
                                 .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                 .andDo(print())
                                 .andExpect(jsonPath("$",hasSize(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario where the stack trace was indicating something similar to your error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].contentId"
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minidev/json/writer/JsonReaderI
```

I found this post: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/159#issuecomment-411306322 which caught my attention. I was using the net.minidev:json-smart:1.1.1 in my project.

What I did was just updating the version to 2.3 and the issue was solved.